# Does ETRS89 and UTM use the same zone (longitude and latitude)?

Tags: coordinate-system, utm

I'm building an app for the european country Denmark exclusively and I need to retrieve some geospatial data from a (geo)server.

I'm currently trying to determine whether UTM and ETRS89 uses the same zone (lng, lat) or if it varies in Denmark especially?

An example for a UTM Zone for Denmark would be: 32U

Comment: Not an answer but a definite place you should be looking at is http://epsg.io/

Comment: Thank you @Hornbydd! I found that website really useful.

Answer (score 3):

First, ETRS 89 is a geographic coordinate system, so you cannot compare it directly with UTM (a projected coordiante system). There is no zonation with ETRS 89 because it is globally valid, to the contrary of UTM which is locally adjusted.

Technically you can use UTM projection with the ETRS89 datum without any problem, and this will be nearly identical to the UTM 32 North based on WGS84 (the "standard" UTM) because ETRS 89 and WGS 84 are nearly identical. Therefore the "zones" would be the same.